# How can I get one result per row? I've already tried with DISTINCT but it doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle

I already got a view with this name and it works well for now. Anyway I need more filter...

I've already tried with DISTINCT but it does not affect results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COD_COMPLESSO,
    NOME_COMPLESSO,
    ID_BM,
    NOME_BM,
    ID_FORNITORE,
    NOME_FORNITORE,
    ANNO,
    MESE,
    DATE_REQUEST,
    SUM(rqm.aperto) AS num_aperto,
    SUM(rqm.in_corso) AS num_in_corso,
    SUM(rqm.chiuso) AS num_chiuso
FROM (
SELECT
    COD_COMPLESSO,
    NOME_COMPLESSO,
    ID_BM,
    NOME_BM,
    ID_FORNITORE,
    NOME_FORNITORE,
    ANNO,
    MESE,
    DATE_REQUEST,
    (CASE WHEN COD_STATUS_CON = 'OPN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS aperto,
    (CASE WHEN COD_STATUS_CON = 'ONG' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS in_corso,
    (CASE WHEN COD_STATUS_CON = 'CLO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS chiuso
FROM V_RQM_REQUEST_BM) rqm 
GROUP BY
    NOME_COMPLESSO, COD_COMPLESSO,
    MESE, ANNO,
    ID_BM, NOME_BM,
    ID_FORNITORE, NOME_FORNITORE,
    DATE_REQUEST;
```

Actual result shows me N row with "xxx" as COD_COMPLESSO but I need only one row with COD_COMPLESSO = 'xxx', another one row with COD_COMPLESSO = 'yyy' and so on... I've already tried adding a DISTINCT in the first and in the second SELECT (even on both), but it seems not working, can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting a row for each distinct one of your entire Grouping. If you check each of your N rows you will find a different value in one of these columns in each of the rows.

```
GROUP BY
NOME_COMPLESSO, COD_COMPLESSO,
MESE, ANNO,
ID_BM, NOME_BM,
ID_FORNITORE, NOME_FORNITORE,
DATE_REQUEST;
```

If you want only one row for each COD_COMPLESSO then start with this, and note you will have to remove or change your SUM()s.

```
 GROUP BY COD_COMPLESSO
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
SELECT COD_COMPLESSO, NOME_COMPLESSO,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COD_STATUS_CON = 'OPN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS aperto,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COD_STATUS_CON = 'ONG' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS in_corso,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COD_STATUS_CON = 'CLO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS chiuso
FROM V_RQM_REQUEST_BM rqm 
GROUP BY NOME_COMPLESSO, COD_COMPLESSO;
```

Selecting the other columns doesn't make sense, if you want only one row per `COD_COMPLESSO`.  There are multiple values.  Which do you want?  If you do want to see something, choose an aggregation function . . . typically `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, `COUNT()`, or `LISTAGG()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. Now I'm dealing with this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
  COD_COMPLESSO,
  NOME_COMPLESSO,
  SUM(rqm.aperto) AS num_aperto,
  SUM(rqm.in_corso) AS num_in_corso,
  SUM(rqm.chiuso) AS num_chiuso
FROM (
 SELECT
  COD_COMPLESSO,
  NOME_COMPLESSO,
  ID_BM,
  NOME_BM,
  ID_FORNITORE,
  NOME_FORNITORE,
  ANNO,
  MESE,
  DATE_REQUEST,
  (CASE WHEN COD_STATUS_CON = 'OPN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS aperto,
  (CASE WHEN COD_STATUS_CON = 'ONG' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS in_corso,
  (CASE WHEN COD_STATUS_CON = 'CLO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS chiuso
 FROM V_RQM_REQUEST_BM
 WHERE COD_COMPLESSO IS NOT NULL AND ID_BM IS NOT NULL AND ID_FORNITORE IS NOT NULL) 
     rqm
 GROUP BY
  COD_COMPLESSO, NOME_COMPLESSO,
  MESE, ANNO,
  ID_BM, NOME_BM,
  ID_FORNITORE, NOME_FORNITORE,
  DATE_REQUEST
  ORDER BY DATE_REQUEST;
```

As you can see I've added a WHERE and an ORDER BY, anyway I can't test it now, I'm not in the office at the moment, tomorrow morining I'll post my results. In the meantime... suggestions are welcome :-)